# <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> not working in test environment?

Tags: c#, .net, meta-tags

We are currently experiencing an issue in IE9 with our Sitefinity CMS and I was able to fix it in my development environment by adding:

to the head tag (before the title). In our test environment this is not working, any thoughts what might cause this?

Answer (score 2):

The tag should be before any other element in the head not just only before title.
Test the result in the browser using the "view source" command to ensure it is the first.

Answer (score 0):

By default IE ignores this meta tag in an intranet scenario and it runs in some sort of a hybrid mode. Take a look and hit F12 (to open IE developer tools) and look at the "Browser Mode" and "Document Mode" to see what I mean (compare to running as localhost). I believe this is to avoid breaking internal applications that were designed for earlier version of IE (doesn't make any sense because you are being explicit though!) Writing an HTTP Response header like this in the web.config has worked for me in the past to force the latest version of IE and not some sort of compatibility mode:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```